# Flutter ; Vertical ListView inside a column(inside another column) causing an overflow

Tags: flutter, listview, overflow, singlechildscrollview

```
class Episodes extends StatefulWidget {
  const Episodes({super.key});

  @override
  State<Episodes> createState() => _EpisodesState();
}

class _EpisodesState extends State<Episodes> {
  final seasons = ['Season 1', 'Season 2', 'Season 3'];

  String? value;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    //EdgeInsets.only(left: size.width * 0.03, right: size.width * 0.03),
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: size.height * 0.045,
            width: size.width * 0.25,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.25),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
            child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
              child: DropdownButton<String>(
                value: value,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                isExpanded: true,
                //icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down_outlined,
                //  size: 12, color: Colors.white),
                iconEnabledColor: Colors.white,

                //dropdownColor: Colors.transparent,
                items: seasons.map(buildMenuItem).toList(),
                dropdownColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
                onChanged: (value) => setState(() {
                  this.value = value;
                }),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: size.height * 0.02),
          ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            //physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            itemCount: 15,
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  height: 15,
                  width: 15,
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  DropdownMenuItem<String> buildMenuItem(String item) => DropdownMenuItem(
      value: item,
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          item,
          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12),
        ),
      ));
}
```

Im trying to  build a netflix clone, and this is the design of the episode list in the title page.
Basically, im trying to include listview.builder(vertical) inside a column; but im getting an overflow error.
This column is furthur getting returned as one of the children of a parent column in another file.

Till now ive tried wrapping the column under :
*SingleChildScrollView,
*Expanded
*SizedBox, Container : with fixed height

None of the above worked; i even tried playing around with the scroll physics, didnt work, the overflow error still persisted.

Im new to flutter; i just wanna get rid of the overflow error. Any help will be appreciated!
Furthur im looking to dynamically fetch details from firebase and display them here. Any tips on that will be appreciated as well!

Main file structure :

```
    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/container.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:netflixclone/ContentPages/tabbar_pg.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

//UpperNavBar
//video preview
//Container
//Name
//{List of particulars}
//Play Btn
//Download Btn
//Description
//Strarring
//creator
//Row List : List, Rate, Share, Download S1.
//Tab Bar : Episodes, TrailersNMore, MoreLikeThis
//DropDownList : Seasons list
//Episodes : E1 : Container :{}..
//TrailersNMore : Vidoes
//MoreLikeThis : 9 random suggestions. : if i can ill do.

class TitlePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TitlePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<TitlePage> createState() => _TitlePageState();
}

class _TitlePageState extends State<TitlePage> {
  int current = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<String> items = [
      "EPISODES",
      "TRAILERS & MORE",
      "MORE LIKE THIS",
    ];
    List<Widget> itemsPages = [
      Episodes(),
      TrailersNMore(),
      MoreLikeThis(),
    ];
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(size.height * 0.05),
        child: UpperAppBar(),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: size.height * 0.007),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(child: VideoController()),
            Container(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: size.width * 0.02,
                    top: size.height * 0.01,
                    right: size.width * 0.02),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text("Peaky Blinders",
                        style: GoogleFonts.comfortaa(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 30,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w900)),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: size.height * 0.008),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Text("2022",
                              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                  color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.99),
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                          SizedBox(width: size.width * 0.03),
                          Container(
                            width: size.width * 0.033,
                            height: size.height * 0.024,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5)),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text("A",
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                      color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.99),
                                      fontSize: 16,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(width: size.width * 0.03),
                          Text("6-Seasons",
                              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                  color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.99),
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                          SizedBox(width: size.width * 0.03),
                          Icon(Icons.comment_rounded,
                              size: 25, color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8))
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      style: ButtonStyle(
                          backgroundColor:
                              MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.white),
                          shape:
                              MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                            RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                            ),
                          ),
                          fixedSize: MaterialStateProperty.all<Size>(
                              Size.fromWidth(size.width))),
                      onPressed: null,
                      child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Icon(
                              Icons.play_arrow,
                              color: Colors.black,
                              size: 22,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: size.width * 0.01),
                            Text('Play',
                                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
                          ]),
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      style: ButtonStyle(
                          backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                              Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.25)),
                          shape:
                              MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                            RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                            ),
                          ),
                          fixedSize: MaterialStateProperty.all<Size>(
                              Size.fromWidth(size.width))),
                      onPressed: null,
                      child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Icon(
                              Icons.download_outlined,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              size: 20,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: size.width * 0.01),
                            Text('Download',
                                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                            SizedBox(width: size.width * 0.01),
                            Text('S1:E1',
                                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                          ]),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'A notorious gang in 1919 Birminham, England, is led by the fierce Tommy Shelby, a crime boss set on moving up in the world no matter the cost.',
                      style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                          color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: size.height * 0.01),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'Starring: ',
                          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                              color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.99),
                              fontSize: 12),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Cillian Murphy,Sam Neill, Helen McCory',
                          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                              color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.7),
                              fontSize: 12),
                        ),
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () => null,
                          child: Text(
                            '...more',
                            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.99),
                                fontSize: 12),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'Creator: ',
                          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                              color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.99),
                              fontSize: 12),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Steven Knight',
                          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                              color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.7),
                              fontSize: 12),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: size.height * 0.01),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: [
                        InkWell(
                          splashColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.8),
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              IconButton(
                                  onPressed: () => null,
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    Icons.check,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    size: 30,
                                  )),
                              Text(
                                'My List',
                                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.7),
                                    fontSize: 10),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        InkWell(
                          splashColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.8),
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              IconButton(
                                  onPressed: () => null,
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    Icons.thumb_up_alt_outlined,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    size: 30,
                                  )),
                              Text(
                                'Rate',
                                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.7),
                                    fontSize: 10),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        InkWell(
                          splashColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.8),
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              IconButton(
                                  onPressed: () => null,
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    Icons.share,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    size: 30,
                                  )),
                              Text(
                                'Share',
                                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.7),
                                    fontSize: 10),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        InkWell(
                          splashColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.8),
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              IconButton(
                                  onPressed: () => null,
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    Icons.download_rounded,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    size: 30,
                                  )),
                              Text(
                                'Download Season 1',
                                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.7),
                                    fontSize: 10),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Divider(
              height: size.height * 0.01,
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.7),
              height: size.height * 0.002,
            ),
            //TabBar :
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: size.width * 0.03, right: size.width * 0.03),
              child: SizedBox(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 60,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                  itemCount: items.length,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                    return GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () => setState(() {
                        current = index;
                      }),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: size.width * 0.1),
                        child: AnimatedContainer(
                          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: current == index
                                ? Border(
                                    top: BorderSide(
                                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 225, 26, 12),
                                        width: size.height * 0.005),
                                  )
                                : Border(
                                    top: BorderSide(
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                        width: size.height * 0.005),
                                  ),
                          ),
                          child: Text(items[index],
                              style: GoogleFonts.bebasNeue(
                                  fontSize: 22,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                  color: current == index
                                      ? Colors.white
                                      : Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.99))),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
             itemsPages[current],
            //Episodes()
            // Container(
            //   width: double.infinity,
            //   child: itemsPages[current],
            // ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget UpperAppBar() {
    return AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      leading: Icon(
        Icons.arrow_back,
        color: Colors.white,
        size: 30,
      ),
      actions: [
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.search,
            color: Colors.white,
            size: 30,
          ),
          onPressed: null,
        ),
        IconButton(
          icon: Image.asset('assets/Images/ProfileImg.jpg', width: 30),
          onPressed: null,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class VideoController extends StatefulWidget {
  const VideoController({super.key});

  @override
  State<VideoController> createState() => _VideoPlayerState();
}

class _VideoPlayerState extends State<VideoController> {
  late VideoPlayerController controller;
  final asset = 'assets/Videos/SoClose-ThomasShelby.mp4';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = VideoPlayerController.asset(asset)
      ..addListener(() => setState(() {}))
      ..setLooping(
          true) //if u can after vid finishes : pause it and add a peaky blinders logo
      ..initialize().then((_) => controller.play());
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final isMuted = controller.value.volume == 0;
    return Stack(children: [
      VideoPlayerWidget(controller: controller),
      if (controller != null && controller.value.isInitialized)
        Positioned(
          top: size.height * 0.185,
          left: size.width * 0.85,
          child: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              isMuted ? Icons.volume_off : Icons.volume_up,
              color: Colors.white,
              size: 20,
            ),
            onPressed: () => controller.setVolume(isMuted ? 1 : 0),
          ),
        ),
      Positioned(
        top: size.height * 0.205,
        left: size.width * 0.02,
        child: Container(
          width: size.width * 0.16,
          height: size.height * 0.026,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.39)),
          child: Center(
            child: Text('Preview',
                style: GoogleFonts.ptSans(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15)),
          ),
        ),
      )
    ]);
  }
}

class VideoPlayerWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final VideoPlayerController controller;

  const VideoPlayerWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.controller,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return controller != null && controller.value.isInitialized
        ? Container(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: buildVideo(),
          )
        : Container(
            height: 100,
            child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
          );
  }

  Widget buildVideo() => Stack(children: <Widget>[
        buildVideoPlayer(),
        Positioned.fill(child: BasicOverlayWidget(controller: controller)),
      ]);

  Widget buildVideoPlayer() => AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
      child: VideoPlayer(controller));
}

class BasicOverlayWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final VideoPlayerController controller;

  const BasicOverlayWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.controller,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => GestureDetector(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
        onTap: () =>
            controller.value.isPlaying ? controller.pause() : controller.play(),
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            buildPlay(),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 0,
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: buildIndicator(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );

  Widget buildIndicator() => VideoProgressIndicator(
        controller,
        allowScrubbing: true,
        colors: VideoProgressColors(
            backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 115, 11, 3),
            playedColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 225, 26, 12)),
      );

  Widget buildPlay() => controller.value.isPlaying
      ? Container()
      : Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          color: Colors.black26,
          child: Icon(Icons.play_arrow, color: Colors.white, size: 80),
        );
}
```

Comment: it is working, can you include more about its parent widget

Comment: Logically it must work, I just can't figure out why this overflow is occurring. I will update the parent file structure as well.

Comment: still failed to reproduce the error, perhaps the issue is coming from another place

Comment: Ive edited the question, please check it out.

Comment: Well,its quite a late reply, but thank you all for your suggestions, I haven't implemented some of them yet; The problem seems a little daunting so I'm going to just let it be and leave the idea of episodes behind. Thanks again !!

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand you have something like this on the main page:

```
Column(children : [
  SomeWidget(),
  OtherWidget(),
  Episodes(),
]);
```

Since Episodes() is in Column, it's been given infinite height. You should wrap it in an Expanded() widget if you want it to get the remaining height of the page, like below.

```
Column(children : [
  SomeWidget(),
  OtherWidget(),
  Expanded(child:Episodes()),
]);
```

If this doesn't fix your problem, please give more informations about the parent widget (where Episodes is used).

Comment: Yup, exactly. The main page is structured the way uve stated. I will try out ur sol and repost a comment on this thread. Thanks!!

Comment: This, unfortunately, didn't solve the issue. Basically, the parent widget is the column as you stated. This column is under a scaffold.

Comment: All the children of your Column should have a specific height (like SizedBox) or be wrapped into a Flexible() widget. Or you could wrap Episodes in a SizedBox or else. But personnaly i'd rather use Flexible and Expanded widget to have a responsive interface.

Could you please give the full code causing the problem ?

Comment: Ive included the entire file this time; If I've written the code with some bad practices, please point them out. Thanks again!

Comment: So you have this atm:
```
Column(children:[
  Container(child:VideoController(), #A
  Container -> Padding -> Column(), #B
  Divider, #C
  Container, #D
  Padding -> SizedBox -> ListView, #E
  ItemPages #which display Episodes(), #F
])
```
Lines A B and F should be given a size. Either by giving size to Container or by wraping them into Flexible() widget https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html . C D and E already have fixed size (nothing to do here). Then, if Episodes() is higher than available sapce, wrap it in SingleChildScrollView.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

- The scaffold wrapper was missing and I fixed it
- I added Area to prevent the height of the MenuItem popup from exceeding the top of the screen

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class Episodes extends StatefulWidget {
  const Episodes({super.key});

  @override
  State<Episodes> createState() => _EpisodesState();
}

class _EpisodesState extends State<Episodes> {
  final seasons = ['Season 1', 'Season 2', 'Season 3'];

  String? value;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    //EdgeInsets.only(left: size.width * 0.03, right: size.width * 0.03),
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: size.height * 0.045,
              width: size.width * 0.25,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.25),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
              child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                child: DropdownButton<String>(
                  value: value,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  isExpanded: true,
                  //icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down_outlined,
                  //  size: 12, color: Colors.white),
                  iconEnabledColor: Colors.white,

                  //dropdownColor: Colors.transparent,
                  items: seasons.map(buildMenuItem).toList(),
                  dropdownColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
                  onChanged: (value) => setState(() {
                    this.value = value;
                  }),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: size.height * 0.02),
            ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              //physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: 15,
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    height: 15,
                    width: 15,
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }

  DropdownMenuItem<String> buildMenuItem(String item) => DropdownMenuItem(
      value: item,
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          item,
          // style: GoogleFonts.poppins(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12),
        ),
      ));
}

//UpperNavBar
//video preview
//Container
//Name
//{List of particulars}
//Play Btn
//Download Btn
//Description
//Strarring
//creator
//Row List : List, Rate, Share, Download S1.
//Tab Bar : Episodes, TrailersNMore, MoreLikeThis
//DropDownList : Seasons list
//Episodes : E1 : Container :{}..
//TrailersNMore : Vidoes
//MoreLikeThis : 9 random suggestions. : if i can ill do.

class TitlePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TitlePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<TitlePage> createState() => _TitlePageState();
}

class _TitlePageState extends State<TitlePage> {
  int current = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<String> items = [
      "EPISODES",
      "TRAILERS & MORE",
      "MORE LIKE THIS",
    ];
    List<Widget> itemsPages = [
      Episodes(),
      Expanded(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: [
                ...List.generate(
                    10,
                    (index) => ListTile(
                          title: Text('$index'),
                        ))
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
          child: Column(
        children: [
          // TrailersNMore(),
          // MoreLikeThis(),
        ],
      ))
    ];
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(size.height * 0.05),
        child: UpperAppBar(),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: size.height * 0.007),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(child: VideoController()),
            Container(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: size.width * 0.02,
                    top: size.height * 0.01,
                    right: size.width * 0.02),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "Peaky Blinders",
                      // style: GoogleFonts.comfortaa(
                      //     color: Colors.white,
                      //     fontSize: 30,
                      //     fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: size.height * 0.008),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            "2022",
                            // style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                            //     color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.99),
                            //     fontSize: 16,
                            //     fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(width: size.width * 0.03),
                          Container(
                            width: size.width * 0.033,
                            height: size.height * 0.024,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5)),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                "A",
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                // style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                //     color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.99),
                                //     fontSize: 16,
                                //     fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(width: size.width * 0.03),
                          Text(
                            "6-Seasons",
                            // style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                            //     color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.99),
                            //     fontSize: 16,
                            //     fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(width: size.width * 0.03),
                          Icon(Icons.comment_rounded,
                              size: 25, color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8))
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      style: ButtonStyle(
                          backgroundColor:
                              MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.white),
                          shape:
                              MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                            RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                            ),
                          ),
                          fixedSize: MaterialStateProperty.all<Size>(
                              Size.fromWidth(size.width))),
                      onPressed: null,
                      child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Icon(
                              Icons.play_arrow,
                              color: Colors.black,
                              size: 22,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: size.width * 0.01),
                            Text(
                              'Play',
                              // style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                              //     color: Colors.black,
                              //     fontSize: 16,
                              //     fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            )
                          ]),
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      style: ButtonStyle(
                          backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                              Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.25)),
                          shape:
                              MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                            RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                            ),
                          ),
                          fixedSize: MaterialStateProperty.all<Size>(
                              Size.fromWidth(size.width))),
                      onPressed: null,
                      child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Icon(
                              Icons.download_outlined,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              size: 20,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: size.width * 0.01),
                            Text(
                              'Download',
                              // style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                              //     color: Colors.white,
                              //     fontSize: 16,
                              //     fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: size.width * 0.01),
                            Text(
                              'S1:E1',
                              // style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                              //     color: Colors.white,
                              //     fontSize: 16,
                              //     fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)，
                            ),
                          ]),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'A notorious gang in 1919 Birminham, England, is led by the fierce Tommy Shelby, a crime boss set on moving up in the world no matter the cost.',
                      // style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                      //     color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: size.height * 0.01),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'Starring: ',
                          // style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                          //     color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.99),
                          //     fontSize: 12),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Cillian Murphy,Sam Neill, Helen McCory',
                          // style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                          //     color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.7),
                          //     fontSize: 12),
                        ),
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () => null,
                          child: Text(
                            '...more',
                            // style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                            //     color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.99),
                            //     fontSize: 12),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'Creator: ',
                          // style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                          //     color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.99),
                          //     fontSize: 12),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Steven Knight',
                          // style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                          //     color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.7),
                          //     fontSize: 12),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: size.height * 0.01),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: [
                        InkWell(
                          splashColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.8),
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              IconButton(
                                  onPressed: () => null,
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    Icons.check,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    size: 30,
                                  )),
                              Text(
                                'My List',
                                // style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                //     color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.7),
                                //     fontSize: 10),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        InkWell(
                          splashColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.8),
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              IconButton(
                                  onPressed: () => null,
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    Icons.thumb_up_alt_outlined,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    size: 30,
                                  )),
                              Text(
                                'Rate',
                                // style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                //     color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.7),
                                //     fontSize: 10),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        InkWell(
                          splashColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.8),
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              IconButton(
                                  onPressed: () => null,
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    Icons.share,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    size: 30,
                                  )),
                              Text(
                                'Share',
                                // style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                //     color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.7),
                                //     fontSize: 10),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        InkWell(
                          splashColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.8),
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              IconButton(
                                  onPressed: () => null,
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    Icons.download_rounded,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    size: 30,
                                  )),
                              Text(
                                'Download Season 1',
                                // style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                //     color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.7),
                                //     fontSize: 10),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Divider(
              height: size.height * 0.01,
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.7),
              height: size.height * 0.002,
            ),
            //TabBar :
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: size.width * 0.03, right: size.width * 0.03),
              child: SizedBox(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 60,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                  itemCount: items.length,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                    return GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () => setState(() {
                        current = index;
                      }),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: size.width * 0.1),
                        child: AnimatedContainer(
                          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: current == index
                                ? Border(
                                    top: BorderSide(
                                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 225, 26, 12),
                                        width: size.height * 0.005),
                                  )
                                : Border(
                                    top: BorderSide(
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                        width: size.height * 0.005),
                                  ),
                          ),
                          child: Text(
                            items[index],
                            // style: GoogleFonts.bebasNeue(
                            //     fontSize: 22,
                            //     fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            //     color: current == index
                            //         ? Colors.white
                            //         : Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.99)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
            itemsPages[current],
            //Episodes()
            // Container(
            //   width: double.infinity,
            //   child: itemsPages[current],
            // ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget UpperAppBar() {
    return AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      leading: Icon(
        Icons.arrow_back,
        color: Colors.white,
        size: 30,
      ),
      actions: [
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.search,
            color: Colors.white,
            size: 30,
          ),
          onPressed: null,
        ),
        IconButton(
          icon: Image.asset('assets/Images/ProfileImg.jpg', width: 30),
          onPressed: null,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class VideoController extends StatefulWidget {
  const VideoController({super.key});

  @override
  State<VideoController> createState() => _VideoPlayerState();
}

class _VideoPlayerState extends State<VideoController> {
  late VideoPlayerController controller;
  final asset = 'assets/Videos/SoClose-ThomasShelby.mp4';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = VideoPlayerController.asset(asset)
      ..addListener(() => setState(() {}))
      ..setLooping(
          true) //if u can after vid finishes : pause it and add a peaky blinders logo
      ..initialize().then((_) => controller.play());
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final isMuted = controller.value.volume == 0;
    return Stack(children: [
      VideoPlayerWidget(controller: controller),
      if (controller != null && controller.value.isInitialized)
        Positioned(
          top: size.height * 0.185,
          left: size.width * 0.85,
          child: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              isMuted ? Icons.volume_off : Icons.volume_up,
              color: Colors.white,
              size: 20,
            ),
            onPressed: () => controller.setVolume(isMuted ? 1 : 0),
          ),
        ),
      Positioned(
        top: size.height * 0.205,
        left: size.width * 0.02,
        child: Container(
          width: size.width * 0.16,
          height: size.height * 0.026,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.39)),
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              'Preview',
              // style: GoogleFonts.ptSans(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
    ]);
  }
}

class VideoPlayerWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final VideoPlayerController controller;

  const VideoPlayerWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.controller,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return controller != null && controller.value.isInitialized
        ? Container(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: buildVideo(),
          )
        : Container(
            height: 100,
            child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
          );
  }

  Widget buildVideo() => Stack(children: <Widget>[
        buildVideoPlayer(),
        Positioned.fill(child: BasicOverlayWidget(controller: controller)),
      ]);

  Widget buildVideoPlayer() => AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
      child: VideoPlayer(controller));
}

class BasicOverlayWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final VideoPlayerController controller;

  const BasicOverlayWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.controller,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => GestureDetector(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
        onTap: () =>
            controller.value.isPlaying ? controller.pause() : controller.play(),
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            buildPlay(),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 0,
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: buildIndicator(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );

  Widget buildIndicator() => VideoProgressIndicator(
        controller,
        allowScrubbing: true,
        colors: VideoProgressColors(
            backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 115, 11, 3),
            playedColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 225, 26, 12)),
      );

  Widget buildPlay() => controller.value.isPlaying
      ? Container()
      : Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          color: Colors.black26,
          child: Icon(Icons.play_arrow, color: Colors.white, size: 80),
        );
}
```

Comment: Yea mate, I've tried this out. Doesn't work. Thanks tho!

Comment: @SowmeshSharma  I have updated the answer.  good luck~

Comment: I have tried this out as well, but it didn't work out. Returning a totally new scaffold, made it worse. Bottom overflowed by inf pixels.

Comment: @Sowmesh please include a complete example, as others will be able to help you more accurately. What is the outer wrapper for Episodes() ?

Comment: Ive included the entire file containing the  parent widget

Comment: @SowmeshSharma  hope it helps you